# Glossaries - Exclude page numbers from certain section

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, glossaries, back-referencing, glossaries-extra

I am using the `glossaries-extra` package in my document. Here is an excerpt:

```latex
\chapter{List of Nicknames}
\label{chapter:nicknames}
% PAGE 4 OF THE OUTPUT PDF
% I am actually using the `acronyms` package in conjunction with `glossaries`, but I removed it from this post in the interest of clarity.
\begin{itemize}
    \item \gls{Joseph} is also called ``Joe."
    \item \gls{Robert} goes by ``Bob."
    \item \gls{Samantha}'s nickname is ``Sam."
\end{itemize}

% ... Some other chapters ...

\chapter{Walmart}
% PAGE 7 OF THE OUTPUT PDF

\gls{Joseph} (Joe) was going to Walmart one day, and he ran into \gls{Robert} (Bob) and \gls{Samantha} (Sam).

% ... Some more paragraphs ...
% PAGE 8 OF THE OUTPUT PDF

When they got into the store, \gls{Joseph} asked \gls{Robert} to give him advice on a critical quandary: should he buy Cheerios or Rice Chex?
```

I want my glossary to look like this:

> **Joe** 7, 8
> (Description of Joe)
>
> **Bob** 7, 8
> (Description of Bob)
>
> **Sally** 7
> (Description of Sally)

... *not* this:

> **Joe** 4, 7, 8
> (Description of Joe)
>
> **Bob** 4, 7, 8
> (Description of Bob)
>
> **Sally** 4, 7
> (Description of Sally)

In other words: when I print the glossary with `\printunsrtglossaries`, I *don't* want the page numbers from the "List of Nicknames" chapter. I *do*, however, want the page numbers of the glossaries references within the "Walmart" chapter. **How can I accomplish this?**

The references on page 4 should still *link* to the glossary entry, but they *should not appear in the page number list*.

---

**I am not looking for an answer that uses the acronyms feature of `glossaries`.** If there is another command that I can use instead of `\gls` (e.g., `\glsNoPageNum` or something) in the "List of abbreviations" chapter, that is fine. If there is a command that I can use to exclude page numbers from the *entire* chapter (e.g., `\glsExcludeNumbersFrom{chapter:nicknames}` or something), that is even better.
Please avoid redefining macros that already exist in a CTAN package.

---